# Find blocks of multiple lines

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel file which contains blocks of rows varying from one to maximum 13 rows in each block, followed by an empty row after each block of data.
I would like to find the blocks that are identical to any other block of rows.
I know I can remove duplicates by using *Remove duplicates* and mark them with Conditional formatting, but that only compares single rows. 
So my question is, **Is there a way to mark these blocks that are identical to another block?**

**EDIT:** To clarify what kind of data I'm talking about: It's a list of steel objects that are produced by welding together several other steel objects. So my data looks a bit like this:

> **Item   ---   Component   ---   Amount required   ---   Other columns...**
>   Item1   ---   Component1   ---   1   ---   ...
>   Item1   ---   Component3   ---   2   ---   ...
>   Item1   ---   Component8   ---   1   ---   ...
>   *Empty row (Only for readability of data, is not neccesary)*
>   Item2   ---   Component3   ---   2   ---   ...
>   Item2   ---   Component4   ---   3   ---   ...
>   *Empty row (Only for readability of data, is not neccesary)*
>   Item3   ---   Component3   ---   2   ---   ...
>   Item3   ---   Component4   ---   3   ---   ...
>   *Empty row (Only for readability of data, is not neccesary)*
>   Item4   ---   Component8   ---   1   ---   ...
>   *Empty row (Only for readability of data, is not neccesary)*
>   ...

As you can see, only the blocks of rows for item 2 and 3 are identical. So these should be marked as duplicate. The third row of the first block and the first row of the fourth block are identical, but since not the entire blocks are identical, these should be ignored.
I hope this clarifies the situation a bit.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data "blocks"? When you say "block", are you referring to a range of cells; i.e. `A1:E15`? What research have you done and what have you attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with some helper column:

1. create a column where you concatenate all component descriptions:
   `=IF(A2=A1,E1&",","")&B2`
2. create a column to show whether a row is the last one of an item:
   `=A2<>A3`
3. in next column you can show whether an item is duplicate:
   `=IF(E2="","",IF(A2=A3,G3,COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$13,E2,$F$2:$F$13,TRUE)>1))`, where:

   - `=IF(E2="","",...)` - just keep cell blank if the line is empty
   - `IF(A2=A3,G3,...)` - distributes the same value for all rows of an item from it's last row (where it has the complete component list)
   - `COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$13,E2,$F$2:$F$13,TRUE)>1)` - checks whether the item is duplicated

[image]

This solution marks all duplicates, it's good to filter for them, if you want to remove them instead, then maybe you don't want to filter for first occurrences, only for repetitions, this case just change reference from `$E$2:$E$13` to `$E$2:$E2`

### Update 1

If order of components is not the same in all the items, then you need to sort them in order to make this process working: at first order by "Component", then by "Item".

Comment: This sure helps, thanks a lot!I only have one additional issue now. Not all the components are listed in the same order in a block. Is it possible to mark these as duplicates too? For example if _Item1_ has _comp1,comp2_ and _item2_ has _comp2,comp1_ they aren't marked as duplicates

Comment: @NilsTiebos: yes, see my update.

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed!